# Can you use Realm Sync with an M0 tier MongoDB cluster?

Tags: database, mongodb, realm

I'm using an MongoDB M0 (free forever) cluster and its on version 4.2.8, it explicitly tells me that I cannot change the version on a M0 cluster. If I set up the Sync thing and click on deploy it tells me that the cluster needs to be on version 4.4 to use Sync. Can I just not use Sync?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit contradictory on this but my guess is *presently* M0 only offers 4.2.

4.4 GA was just released days ago. I expect M0 to upgrade to 4.4 at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now, as you can see [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy3bC.png).
I did it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it is restricted to AWS region us-east-1 as you can see in [Atlas M0 (Free Tier), M2, and M5 Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/#atlas-free-tier)